# difficulty initialising Amazon AWS php SDK - Class Aws\Common\Aws not found

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, classnotfoundexception, aws-sdk

I'm trying to instantiate the Amazon AWS SDK PHP with the following code:

```
require("../aws/aws-autoloader.php");

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\Common\Aws;


// Instantiate the client.

$aws = Aws::factory('awsConfig.php');
$s3Client = $aws->get('s3');
```

I'm however getting returned the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'Aws\Common\Aws' not found

The aws-autoloader file has not been modified from the source so not entirely sure why it's not finding the class?

Answer (score 3):

You're using AWS SDK for PHP v3, while trying to execute code for AWS SDK for PHP v2. You should use `Aws\Sdk` instead of `Aws\Common\Aws`.

AWS provides a migration guide highlighting the differences between version 2 and version 3:

> From Version 3 of the SDK
>
> Key differences:
>
> Use the Aws\Sdk class instead of Aws\Common\Aws.
>
> No configuration file. Use an array for configuration instead.
>
> The 'version' option is required during instantiation.
>
> Use the create() methods instead of get('').